# Executing an exec() or system() in PHP and do not wait for output

Tags: php, command, system, exec, delay

I want to trigger a shell command in eider exec() or system() from PHP script but it is a task that take a while to complete, is there a way to trigger it and continue running the PHP page load without delay?

Edit: I am on CentOS 6, PHP 5.3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depends on the OS you are using.

For linux:

```
pclose(popen("php somefile.php &","r"));
```

notice the amperstand at the end (very important).

For windows:

```
pclose(popen("start php.exe somefile.php","r"));
```

here the `start` keyword is important.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried `exec("php video_processor.php &");` and delay is the same, then also if I set a `sleep(10)` inside video_processor.php then my parent script also waits for 10 seconds.

Comment: Try with `pclose(popen("php video_processor.php &","r"));` or `pclose(popen("/usr/bin/php video_processor.php &","r"));` (I assume your PHP is installed in the default location)

Comment: It worked with this one: `pclose(popen("php video_processor.php &","r"));` so then I edited mine and it worked: `pclose(popen("ffmpeg -i 'videos/sample.mp4' -qmax 1 -vframes 1 -ss 80 videos/images/1.jpg &","r"));` Thank you. :party: :)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how easy and simple this is to do!  Brilliant solution!  I have researched this at some length before and every other solution recommended complex strategies for forking or threading a PHP process.

Comment: Windows specific comment: 
I used to use: pclose(popen("start /B php.exe somefile.php","r"));
as of Windows 10 Creators Update (1703) - the "/B" background switch for "start" command doesnt work. Glad to see that it isnt needed.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but you should consider doing your video conversion work in a background process with either a cron job or using a queue such as Beanstalkd.

This way you can stack up your ffmpeg work in the background without blocking your webserver.

I've had a lot of success with both methods (cron / queue) in the past.

Some other posts about background processes:

[php execute a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)

[Run a ffmpeg process in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198052/run-a-ffmpeg-process-in-the-background)

[Using ffmpeg, PHP and beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592211/using-ffmpeg-php-and-beanstalk)

Some tools you might find useful:

http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

[PEAR System_Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon)

[Pheanstalk, a Beanstalkd library for PHP](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk)

Answer (score 2):

What I do:

```
public function post_create()
{
    ob_end_clean();
    header("Connection: close");
    ignore_user_abort(); // optional
    ob_start();
    echo "Tell ajax to gtfo!";

    $size = ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    ob_end_flush(); // Strange behaviour, will not work
    flush();            // Unless both are called !
    // Do processing here
}
```

Comment: Seems to work with just `header('Content-Length:0');flush();` for me

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
shell_exec("nohup yourcommand > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &");
```

Edit: sorry, dunno why I excluded the & to put it to bg
2> redirects STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null.

Comment: Command runs but the delay is there, this is the full command: `shell_exec("ffmpeg -i 'videos/sample.mp4' -qmax 1 -vframes 1 -ss 80 videos/images/1.jpg 2> /dev/null");`

Comment: try: shell_exec("nohup ffmpeg -i 'videos/sample.mp4' -qmax 1 -vframes 1 -ss 80 videos/images/1.jpg > /dev/null 2> /dev/null")

Comment: Same delay, command executed fine. Maybe ffmpeg just acts differently?

Comment: Just tested this myself with PHP and ffmpeg and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Well use an ajax request to activate the exec part ...then continue with the other tasks

Comment: It would probably work but there should be an easier and more reliable way, like a parameter at the end of exec() or system();

Comment: I don't get the -1 level. Guy gave a short answer. Maybe disliked, but still a fair one.

Comment: After trying any other solution finally managed to make it work using your suggestion. Thank you very much!